# error in sending post in Android

Tags: android, http, post

I am trying to send POST data to a server in the same subnet. Following is my code. But after executing the code I am getting the foll error: "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.x.x refused".

We have given the permission to access internet in the manifest file. When we give this permission, the app terminates whenever we try to launch it. When we remove the permission from the manifest file, the app doesn't terminate but gives the error "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.x.x refused".

```
package com.example.posthtml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        postData();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.x.x/Angelhack/app/create_cause.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "gdfg"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", "ddfgdfg"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", "67546456"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", "pune"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag_1", "dfgdfg"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag_2", "gfdgdg"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag_3", "fddfhfg"));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("Executed\n");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Perfect",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
} 

}
```

Here is the log cat

```
// This i11-08 14:43:36.642: D/AndroidRuntime(1952): Shutting down VM
11-08 14:43:36.642: W/dalvikvm(1952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a82b90)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Process: com.example.posthtml, PID: 1952
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.posthtml/com.example.posthtml.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.example.posthtml.MainActivity.postData(MainActivity.java:62)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.example.posthtml.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-08 14:43:36.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace ? I'm sure you're getting a `NetworkOnMainThread` exception. Try to wrap your HTTP stuff in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @ZouZou http://pastebin.com/jJfwUvGL. Thanks for your reply. Meanwhile I am trying to run as AsyncTask.

Comment: @ZouZou While using Async, device tries little longer to connect, but the error remains the same.

Comment: What error ? NetworkOnMainThread ?

Comment: Error : "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to hhttp://192.168.x.x refused"

Comment: Did you add the right permission ? Are you able to reach http://192.168.x.x from your mobile web browser ? Is this `hhttp://192.168.x.x refused` or `http://192.168.x.x refused` ? Because you have 2 `h` which may cause the error.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access the website from my mobile web browser. In fact, I have another PHP file which returns a row from database on the server as a JSON object. I fetch the JSON object and parse using the foll file which works completely fine. http://pastebin.com/ZXRt0Tv2
I'm sorry I didn't quite get what you meant by having 2 h?

Comment: Don't use == to compare Strings. Use equals()(i.e : `method.equals("POST")`). By two `h` I mean that you said _"HttpHostConnectException: Connection to hhttp://192.168.x.x refused"_ There is 2 h in `hhttp`, so that may cause the error (there is en extra h)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :) Oh... and the extra h is a typo on my part. Sorry. I'll edit the original question accordingly.

Comment: What I find weird is how I can retrieve data but not post it?

Comment: Are you getting the same execption ? Try to relaunch the app and post the logcat error message in your original post.

Comment: Posted the logcat. Btw, We have given the permission to access internet in the manifest file. When we give this permission, the app terminates whenever we try to launch it. When we remove the permission from the manifest file, the app doesn't terminate but gives the error "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.x.x refused". This sounds important to me for some reason. Can't figure ut the problem.

Comment: _"Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"_ Are you sure you move all the HTTP stuff on an AsyncTask. Try to fix that and don't remove the permissions.

Comment: Our async code doesn't seem to work... I'll try it again... meanwhile this not-so-good solution works `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); ` Thanks a ton for all the help. :)

Comment: Btw, I have absolutely no idea what these 3 lines actually do.

Comment: The documentation is your friend =)